# Mac OS X Terminal Zip Utility Doesn't Work with dSYM files

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, zip

I'm trying to zip an iOS dSYM file to upload to Xamarin Insights with a shell script (we're using VSTS release management with a locally hosted Mac OS X build agent).

I'm trying to figure out how to zip up the dSYM file, so I'm trying this command in the Mac Terminal:

```
$ cd /path/to/ipa/folder
$ zip SymbolFiles.zip *.dSYM
```

The output is:

```
updating: MyApp.app.dSYM/ (stored 0%)
```

The resulting zip file is only 206 bytes while the dSYM file is 127.2MB. When I unzip the resulting `SymbolFiles.zip` I get a 0 byte MyApp.app.dSYM file.

Any ideas?

I've also tried

```
$ cd /path/to/ipa/folder
$ zip SymbolFiles.zip MyApp.app.dSYM
```

Comment: I experience a similar hanging when initiating the compression by right clicking the file and selecting > Compress "blah.app.dSYM". It hangs with a full progress bar saying "Preparing to compress 0 files" macOS Sierra 10.12.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

dSYM files are technically folders, so you need to do a recursive compression.

Try

```
zip -r SymbolFiles.zip MyApp.app.dSYM
```

or

```
zip -r SymbolFiles.zip *.dSYM
```

Look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) for more details on command line parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same confusing issue.

If you are INSIDE of a "Show Package Contents" option you cannot zip a file in there. eg. trying to zip the `dsym` inside of a `.xcarchive`

- **copy** (do not *move*) the file(s) to the desktop
- right click > compress; or otherwise zip

## violá